# Fetch live sports data that changes from website to Google sheets

Tags: database, google-sheets, live, android-glide

Update:
I have found a better website for getting the data. If you press my link, you can see in the top of the screen there are multiple future games. I would like to get details about the games that BC Copenhagen plays. The details should be live stats (points, players' points...). Is this possible?

Website: https://basketligaen.dk/

---

I have a pretty difficult question.
I want to fetch live data from a basketball game website. However, this is very tricky, because first of all:
The live games change all the time, and I'm only interested when one team is playing: "BC Copenhagen". (However, if I get more data from different teams, that would work as well)
When you click on the list, you get moved to a detailed screen about the live game. And this is the data I'm interested in.
So I need to somehow get data from the live games. Is it even possible to do this with Excell commands, or do I need to work with APIs like Zapier or Make? However, I have no idea how to do this.
Do you maybe have to give the Link to the game every time the game starts? But this would really not be a reliable solution.
Note: I'm using this data for a Glide App
Website: https://official.mvpapp.dk/live.php

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455)/[images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easier to copy/paste as well**. Your question may be closed, if it isn't self contained. [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [IMPORTHTML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339), but the link provided above shows no data for me. Most likely this requires much more scripting than that. Ideally, there would be an API data feed that could be used. Again, I see no data, so I can't say for sure.

A worst case scenario would be using [#google-apps-scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) to parse the listing of games, grab the game you want, and get the data from that page. That would be out of scope of a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: I have updated my post, maybe the new website can help with a solution.